# Flask webpage - need to display a list of users and permit an admin to select multiple entries

Tags: python, html, flask, bootstrap-4, flask-wtforms

I'm new to Python flask coding and i have a user list.  I need to display this list in an html webpage and permit the admin to select multiple entries.  These users will then be contacted with a broadcast message.
I really just need to know which Bootstrap list type would work best.  thank you in advance!

Comment: Flask installation has a bunch of examples to be reused.

Answer (score 0):

I utilized the following jinja2 code to cycle through my list of users:

```
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ legend }}</legend>

                {% for user in users %}
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ user.email }}">
                        {{ user.username + ": " + user.email }}
                    </label>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
      </div>
    </form>
    {% if form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```